# Multiple file upload as a directory

Tags: jsp, upload

I'm trying to upload multiple file as a directory using jsp.
And I made a multiple file upload But the directory structure is broken.

This is fileUploadForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*"%>
<body>
    <form action="fileUpload.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Mobile Engine Signature Upload</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Engine Signature</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="engine" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and this is fileUpload.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*, com.oreilly.servlet.*, java.util.Enumeration, java.io.*"%>
<% String uploadPath = request.getRealPath("engine");

int size = 10*1024*1024;
String filename="";
String path="";

try{
    MultipartRequest multi=new MultipartRequest(request,uploadPath,size,"euc-kr",new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());

    Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();
    String engine = (String)files.nextElement();
    filename = multi.getFilesystemName(engine);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>

<body>
<form name="filecheck" action="fileCheck.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="engine" value="<%=filename %>">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:filecheck.submit()">Check Upload and go to Download Page</a>
</body>
```

Comment: How is it broken?

Comment: @bunbun Hello, I uploaded a directory that has subdirectory but after uploading, there was no sub directory.
Every files were uploaded in root directory.

Comment: Like,,,
I tried to upload local directory "Root" that looks like "Root/Sub1/Sub2/test.txt".
But, on Server, "Root/test.txt" was result.